# How can I use Pick to select items in one list when a value in a corresponding list is $\leq$ some value?

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine I have two lists:

```
List1 = {0, 1, 0.6, 0.5, 1.2, 0.4};
List2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
```

How can I use `Pick` to return a third list consisting of items in List2 that have a array position corresponding to an array position with a value $\leq N$ in the first list?  Here, for example, for $N = 0.5$ we should have:

```
List3 = {"a", "d", "f"}
```

Comment: Without `Pick`: `Last /@ Select[Transpose@{List1, List2}, #[[1]] <= 0.5 &]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Several ways to create the stencil. Perhaps most intuitive is just to run a test:

```
stencil = # <= 0.5 & /@ List1

Pick[List2, stencil]
(*  {"a", "d", "f"}  *)
```

**Edit**

To answer the comment below, `Pick` "picks out those elements of *list* for which the corresponding element of *sel* is `True`" so the second list as argument to `Pick` has to be a list of `True`/`False` unless a specific pattern is specified.

So the "default" approach above creates a new list of `True`/`False` from `List1`. An alternative is to specify a pattern:

```
Pick[List2, List1, x_ /; x <= 0.5]
(* {"a", "d", "f"} *)
```

or

```
Pick[List2, List1, _?(# <= 0.5 &)]
(* {"a", "d", "f"} *)
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  This may sound like an odd comment, however, how was I supposed to know how to do that?  I spent some time reading the manual before asking this question, and it still wasn't clear how to get the syntax right to solve the problem myself.

Comment: In version 8, `Pick` has improved performance for a packed array stencil (or, as I would call it, mask). One can generate this using a compiled function, in case the test is more complex than a simple threshold. If a threshold's all that's required, chyanog's approach accomplishes the same thing more simply. @SparsePine with over 4000 functions, nobody could be expected to learn and remember them all. This kind of thing comes from experience and, since `Pick` has been around for a while, perhaps there is also an advantage to having used *Mathematica* since it was a much smaller system.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I was trying to keep it simple :)

Comment: @SparsePine `Pick` is full of surprises and its actual behaviour not very well documented. See [this conversation in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9075494#9075494) where some long-time users are puzzled by its behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

You can also use `UnitStep`, it has the Listable attribute, listable operations will be faster than other alternatives.

```
List1 = {0, 1, 0.6, 0.5, 1.2, 0.4};
List2 = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"};
Pick[List2, UnitStep[0.5 - List1], 1]
(*{"a", "d", "f"}*)
```